# Running CodeIgniter on Zend Server Community Edition

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-server-ce

I am just wondering if I could run CodeIgniter applications on Zend Server Community Edition without any issues.

I don't want to mess everything up by experimenting. Please let me know if you have faced any problems running CI on ZendServer CE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know enough about Zend Server to say for sure (e.g. I've seen someone manage to wedge CI into Joomla before), and while I'm sure it's possible, I imagine it would require a lot of tinkering. What you can do is pick and choose your favorite bits of CI or Zend and reuse the code as libraries. Are you being forced to use Zend but would prefer to use CI? If that's the case, I feel for you, but I'm not sure the best solution is to use two entire frameworks with all the overhead that comes with them...it would probably end up being really unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Server isn't really a server. It's just a preconfigured PHP installation for Apache/IIS. When deploying a Zend Framework application, you have to include the Zend Framework libraries along with your application as if you were deploying it on a regular Apache/PHP server.

You can treat it as a stock installation of PHP.